# I want the map method to loop 4 times when I receive data from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used the map method in react to display the data I get from the server, but I do not want all the data to be displayed, I just want 4 numbers to be displayed, please help

```
                              {courses.map((course) => (
                                <section key={course._id}>
                                    <Link to={`/course/${course._id}`} className="img-layer">
                                        <img className="h-100 w-100" src={`https://ghorbany.dev/${course.imageUrl}`} />
                                    </Link>{' '}
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h2 className="card-title">
                                            <Link to={`/course/${course._id}`}>{course.title}</Link>
                                        </h2>
```

Comment: ' I just want 4 numbers to be displayed ', 4 first courses ? or 4 last courses ? or what ?

Comment: Sorry, my information was not complete. I want the last 4 numbers uploaded to the server        @BinaryMan

Comment: dont worry, check out my response

Comment: If you want to upload, you'll have to POST or PUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have this array:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

To get the **first** n elements:

```
a.slice(0, n)
```

To get the **last** n elements:

```
a.slice(Math.max(a.length - n, 0))
```

Exampels:

get 4 first elements from a:

```
a.slice(0, 4); //will return [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

get 4 last elements from a:

```
a.slice(Math.max(a.length - 4, 0)); //will return [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: My dear friend, I can not define an array. An array or object is inside the server. How can I define an array when it is inside the server? @BinaryMan

Comment: Yes I wanted to see how I can access it. I use this address to display courses 
   http ://localhost:3000/archive

Comment: You don't need to define the array. The array prototype has slice and map methods. 
Here are other methods arrays have: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: I realized and my problem was solved, thank you dear friend

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. You can slice the array and then map on them

```
const course = ['course-1', 'course-2', 'course-3', 'course-4']

const items = list.slice(0, 4) 

items.map(() => ...)
```

or check for the index in map function once it's 4 then return null

here is an example. https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-star-s931g?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: My dear friend, I can not define an array. An array or object is inside the server. How can I define an array when it is inside the server? @sodhi Saab

Comment: ignore the first example, check the this  https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-star-s931g?file=/src/App.tsx